# How java default API functions call operating system services?

Tags: java

How java default API functions call operating system services through JVM?

Comment: What are `java default API functions`? Native methods are one way to invoke system services.

Answer (score 4):

Either through normal calls to OS libraries (like windoes dll:s) done by the JVM as required when executing the compiled java bytecode, or through API methods that are explicitly defined as native, in which case they invoke exported native functions in the java runtime libraries (the native java dll:s in the case of windows), who in turn may call functions in other native libraries.

Answer (score 2):

> The Java Native Interface (JNI) is a programming framework that enables Java code running in a Java Virtual Machine (JVM) to call and to be called[1] by native applications (programs specific to a hardware and operating system platform) and libraries written in other languages such as C, C++ and assembly.

Shamelessly copied from wikipedia ("JNI"). The JNI is part of every JRE/JDK and a lot of Java methods in the JRE call native code through JNI.

Answer (score 2):

That question needs some rephrasing, I'm afraid. But I'm assuming you wish to know how the Java API gets its job done.

A lot of it is written in Java itself, but some basic things that absolutely require the cooperation of the operating system and underlying hardware are written for a specific platform (most likely in C/C++) and are called upon through JNI, the Java Native Interface. This is the reason why the JVM is platform-specific.